# problems writing a pandas DataFrame into a unicode text file

Tags: python, unicode, pandas

I have written a program to generate a unicode text file to upload into a website. I have successfully prototyped this particular file using Microsoft Access and have noted that the website rejects the file as not a unicode text file if it is encoded as a utf-8 file. From the text editor (using Windows Notepad), if I save the file using just the unicode encoding in the drop-down box, the website I'm uploading into accepts the file just fine.

So, with this context in mind, I've written a program to autogenerate the file using pandas and DataFrames. The last line of my program exports the DataFrame to a text file:

```
 coa1.to_csv('0000-2951-test.txt',index=False, sep='\t', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

This generates the right file but when I open it in Notepad, the encoding listed is ANSI and not unicode. How do I write my DataFrame to a unicode file? And what kind of unicode does Notepad mean by Unicode (when it doesn't have any additional qualifiers)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"unicode" is not one particular encoding but a set of encodings. It can be utf-8, utf-16, utf-32. [more detailed explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings)

in Windows, unicode often means utf-16, and it is possible that this website expects utf-16. try to encode your csv in utf-16 and see if it is "unicode" in Notepad and this website accepts it.

```
coa1.to_csv('0000-2951-test.txt',index=False, sep='\t', encoding = 'utf-16')
```

**EDIT** Instead of using Windows Notepad, I suggest to use a more decent text editor for your prototyping, which enables to precisely set the encoding. I would use [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) or Notepad++

Comment: Well, the system accepted the file but there are a lot of Asian characters now at the end of each row of data and that's being read by the website as an incorrect format.

Comment: Ok. So I got Notepad++ and it is confirming that my prototype files are encoded as UCS-2LE but the new file I'm generating using python, pandas, and DataFrames is adding a bunch of junk at the end of each line if I encode with UTF-16LE.

Comment: End when you encode it with UTF-8, then there is no junk added?

Comment: That's correct: end with UTF-8 and I don't get any junk. But then the website I need to accept the file doesn't recognize it as a unicode file and rejects the file. @bpgergo

Comment: This is strange, I don't understand how this could happen. This is what I would do to clarify the problem. I'd have pandas encode the file with utf-8. Then I would use standard converter program [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.1.html) to convert it from utf-8 to utf-16 and see if it is identical to the pandas utf-16 version, and see if it contains garbage and accepted by the website. `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 utf8file.txt > utf16file.txt`

Comment: Had some problems with the iconv package but adding this block to my code did successfully eliminate the junk at the end of each line and the website recognized the file as a unicode file: 
     import codecs
     with codecs.open('0000-2951-test.txt', "r", "utf-8") as sourceFile:
     with codecs.open('2951.txt', "w", "utf-16") as targetFile:
            while True:
                     contents = sourceFile.read()
            if not contents:
                 break
            targetFile.write(contents)
Thanks for helping me find a solution @bpgergo